# Clear Named Range Based On User's Selection - ALMOST THERE

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I'm pretty much here with this (following on from yesterday).

But I'm missing something very obvious to some of you guys and not to me.

How do I get the user's selection to be recognized by the clearRange function to be the Named Range to be cleared?

```js
function onOpen() {
    var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
    var mainMenu = ui.createMenu("Clear Tenant Details");
    mainMenu.addItem("Select 'Current Tenant' Range To Reset", "SelectRange");
    mainMenu.addSeparator();
      mainMenu.addItem("Select 'Prospective Tenant' Range To Reset", "SelectRange");
    mainMenu.addToUi();
    ui.showSidebar(createUI());
}
function SelectRange() {
    var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
    var result = ui.prompt('Current Tenant Range Reset', 'Please enter the Unit to reset e.g. ADA_current :', ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
    var button = result.getSelectedButton();
    var targetRange = result.getResponseText();
    if (button == ui.Button.OK) {
        clearRange(targetRange);
} 
      function clearRange() {
  //replace 'Sheet1' with your actual sheet name
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet17');
        sheet.getRange(targetRange).clearContent();
}
}
```

This line seems to be the offender:

sheet.getRange(**targetRange**).clearContent();

What do I put in the brackets so that the response given by the use determines the range which is cleared?

Thanks in advance.

H

Comment: Not sure what I did, but it's just worked!

Comment: Now I just need a way to evoke a pop-up warning message in the event the user's selection is not a recognized Named Range. Can anyone provide a piece of code that does this?

Answer (score 0):

Here it works fine. I changed it to the active sheet with .getActiveSheet()

PS: You can use shortkey fn + TAB (mac) to auto-indent your script in Google Apps Script.

```
function SelectRange() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var result = ui.prompt('Current Tenant Range Reset', 'Please enter the Unit to reset e.g. ADA_current :', ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
  var button = result.getSelectedButton();
  var targetRange = result.getResponseText();
  if (button == ui.Button.OK) {
    clearRange(targetRange);
  } 
  function clearRange() {
    //replace 'Sheet1' with your actual sheet name
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
    sheet.getRange(targetRange).clearContent();
  }
}
```

Comment: That's great! Any idea about the last bit - return error if Range not recognised?

Comment: You should validate the variable targetRange by the regexp /[A-Z][0-9]+/
In code this will be: if( /[A-Z][0-9]+/.test(targetRange ) === false) { // ui.alert("..."); ; return; }

Comment: Hi Wim, thank you for your input. Much appreciated. I have pasted this code in, but it is not yielding the desire outcome. :( What am I missing?

Comment: I am not sure I need to validate targetRange. Instead, I am just looking to trigger an alert in the event that the outcome of the script results in 'Range not found'.

Comment: It's ok Wim, I've sorted it now. Thanks for your help. :)